# Object does not support the property or method for setParameter method while creating Filtered Subgrid in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a filtered sub grid in crm 2011.
I found the following link which describe how to make it:
http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117/p/76157/140281.aspx

This is how it is recommanded to build the code:

```
var relatedOHSOrders = document.getElementById("OHSOrderSubGrid_d"); //Set Subgrid Id
var fetchXml = "..."
relatedOHSOrders.control.setParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml);
```

The problem I have is I get `Object does not support .setParameter property or method` and when I debbug it I do not see setParameter under `relatedOHSOrders.control.`
I Uninstalled and reinstalled rollup 11 just in case but still having the same issue!

Please note I tried other way to use setParameter. The below code also does not work

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("OHSOrderSubGrid")._control.get_innerControl();
relatedOHSOrders.setParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml);
```

It seems that everybody using this code to have filter subgrid but I am not sure what is my problem that it does not show up.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

As you could know the latest update rollup for Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-premises and service update for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online includes significant changes in the web application in order to be able to support a variety of browsers. Have a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2795627

The script that you are trying to use was working in the previous RUP versions of CRM.
The **setParameter** function is no longer available. Now you can use **SetParameter** instead of it. Fortunately **refresh** function is still available. So change the function name in your code and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question myself. The below code perfectly works

```
function setOhsOrderGrid()
{
   var relatedOrders = document.getElementById("OrderSubGrid"); //Set Subgrid Id

    //If this method is called from the form OnLoad, make sure that the grid is loaded before   proceeding
    if (relatedOrders == null || relatedOrders.readyState != "complete") {
        //The subgrid hasn't loaded, wait 1 second and then try again
        setTimeout('setOhsOrderGrid()', 1000);
        return;
    }

    var fetchXml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
    fetchXml += "<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' output-format='xml-platform'    version='1.0'>"; 
    fetchXml += "<entity name='new_ohsorder'> <attribute name='new_orderid'/>";
    fetchXml += "<attribute name='new_order_no'/>";
    fetchXml += "<attribute name='createdon'/>"; 
    fetchXml += "<order descending='false' attribute='new_order_no'/>";
    fetchXml += "<filter type='and'> <condition attribute='new_clientcontactid' value='{1E9A621B-ACA1-E011-9A67-005056A8002D}' uitype='new_clientcontact' uiname='OHS-000001-6FBC4-CCR-01' operator='eq'/>";
    fetchXml += "</filter>";
    fetchXml += "</entity>";
    fetchXml += " </fetch>";

    relatedOrders.control.setParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); --> It breaks
   relatedOrders.control.refresh();  --> It breaks

};
```

setOhsOrderGrid();

---

I had to change var relatedOrders = document.getElementById("OrderSubGrid_d") to
var relatedOrders = document.getElementById("OrderSubGrid")

---

I got a comment that setParameter is unsupported. I don't know why and how I could know that. because setParameter  document.getElementById("OrderSubGrid").control.setParameter !!!
Does anybody have any idea?
And I wonder if anybody know how to code a filter subgrid in a supported way!??

Comment: WIthout exception, anytime you are accessing the DOM (ie using document object), it is unsupported.
The only supported methods to modify a CRM form are using the Xrm object

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `control.setParameter` with `control.SetParameter`.

For more details please have a look at this [MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5722d056-07ba-4410-a6b0-59703963e00e/obeject-does-not-support-the-property-or-method-for-setparameter-method-in-crm-2011-javascript?forum=crm).